# android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "(": syntax error (code 1):

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite

I want to create table in DB, but I get `SQLiteException`:

This is my SQL-request for creating table:

```
String SQL_CREATE_TEMP_CATALOG_CAR_TABLE  = "CREATE TABLE temp_dn_catalog_car (\n"+
        "  catalog_car_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT(11) NOT NULL, \n"+
        "  model_id INTEGER KEY(11) NOT NULL, \n"+
        "  generation_id INTEGER KEY(11) NOT NULL, \n"+
        "  body_type_id INTEGER KEY(11) NOT NULL, \n"+
        "  modification_id INTEGER KEY(11) NOT NULL, \n"+
        "  begin_year INTEGER(11) NOT NULL, \n"+
        "  end_year INTEGER(11) NOT NULL);\n";
```

Error code:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "(": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE temp_dn_catalog_car (  catalog_car_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT(11) NOT NULL,   model_id INTEGER KEY(11) NOT NULL,   generation_id INTEGER KEY(11) NOT NULL,   body_type_id INTEGER KEY(11) NOT NULL,   modification_id INTEGER KEY(11) NOT NULL,   begin_year INTEGER(11) NOT NULL,   end_year INTEGER(11) NOT NULL);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String SQL_CREATE_TEMP_CATALOG_CAR_TABLE  = "CREATE TABLE temp_dn_catalog_car (+
    "  catalog_car_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, +
    "  model_id INTEGER KEY(11) NOT NULL, +
    "  generation_id INTEGER KEY(11) NOT NULL, +
    "  body_type_id INTEGER KEY(11) NOT NULL, +
    "  modification_id INTEGER KEY(11) NOT NULL, +
    "  begin_year INTEGER(11) NOT NULL, +
    "  end_year INTEGER(11) NOT NULL); ";
```

Comment: I am not sure its perfect or not .Just remove `/n` and `AUTOINCREMENT(11)`

Comment: Courtesy goes to @lad2025

Answer (score 1):

Remove `\n` characters and `AUTOINCREMENT(11)` to `AUTOINCREMENT`:

```
String SQL_CREATE_TEMP_CATALOG_CAR_TABLE  = 
       "CREATE TABLE temp_dn_catalog_car (catalog_car_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,model_id INTEGER NOT NULL, generation_id INTEGER  NOT NULL, body_type_id INTEGER NOT NULL, modification_id INTEGER NOT NULL, begin_year INTEGER NOT NULL, end_year INTEGER NOT NULL); ";
```

**[SqlFiddleDemo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!5/fc44a/1)**

Comment: @ShevchenkoArtem And you cannot share error code, right?

Comment: @ShevchenkoArtem post logcat ,Because this answer probably perfect

Comment: @ShevchenkoArtem `AUTOINCREMENT(11)` => `AUTOINCREMENT`